# With 7z-bash, how can I extract specific filetype but keep folder structure?

Tags: bash, 7-zip

As it is right now you can recursively extract files via command parameters, and filter files by type. But if you add a filetype filter they will be extracted into the destination folder.

```
7z.exe x "$filename" -o$destiny -r *.png
```

**Archive structure**

```
img1.png
cmd.exe
dir1/img1.png
dir1/config.ini
dir1/img2.png
dir2/img1.png
```

But it will try to overwrite the corresponding `img1.png` and tries to drop all `.png` files in one folder.

**Desired output structure:**

```
img1.png
dir1/img1.png
dir1/img2.png
dir2/img1.png
```

Is there a convenient way to extract it like this, or do I have to manually create filelists and extract them one-by-one?

Comment: What does bash have to do with this?

Comment: I tried to improve the title. Originally you wrote "7z-bash" as if it was supposed to be treated like a single word; I kept it this way. But what is this "7z-bash" anyway? In the questions there is `7z.exe`. Is this in Windows? Do you run `z7.exe` in Bash in Windows? Please clarify by [edit]ing the question.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski it's the windows variant, so yes. (Git bash)

Comment: That's how the command you showed should work (`x`). I'm confused. You should start with correcting invalid 7z-bash in title, then add some more info, e.g. your 7z version.